# how to calculate device height for tablet and iphone and make a content fixed at its bottom

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, tablet

Can i calculate device width and height for all tablet and ipad devices and make a content fixed at its bottom.

is this possible with jquery or other techniques

Comment: If I understood your question, You can do that with pure **CSS**, [example](http://jsbin.com/ibayar/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

The fixed is positioning is just partial supported at android browsers. You need to fix the elements using JavaScript

maybe this could help you http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/